# Cannot lift sails: localhost undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, localhost, sails.js

I'm on a project using a stack that includes PostgreSQL, NodeJS, SailsJS, and BackboneJS. I pulled the client and server repos from git and I navigate into the server for the project and try to run it:

```
sails lift
```

Then I get this error:

```
/Users/$USER/Documents/Code/$APP/config/adapters.js:39

    host: mc.dbSettings.host,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined
```

Where mc is a var that is set to point to another mainConfig.js file using a require statement. Opening that file I see that dbSettings is defined as:

```
dbSettings: {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "_appName_",
    password: "_password_",
    dbName: "_appDB_"
},
```

and sails cannot initialize because there is no localhost, or it doesn't know what it is? Please help.

Comment: I do have PostgreSQL set up with a DB and user/pass of the same credentials in the mainConfig.js file.

Comment: What version of SailJS are you using? From the docs: `Keep in mind that options you define directly in your model definitions will override these settings. Prior to v0.10, adapters were defined in myApp/config/Adapters.js. See v0.9 docs for more info.`

Comment: I am running 0.10.1 . I am new to sails so sorry your whole point went over my head. Yes, I understand it is an excerpt from the documentation, but can you explain please what you are drawing attention to by posting that?

Comment: Can you show your `require` statement?  Also, try `console.log(mc)` and see what it spits out in the console?

Answer (score 0):

If you're `require`ing a file and getting an "undefined" error trying to access its contents, it's possible you haven't exported the file contents properly.  Your config file should look something like:

```
module.exports = {

    dbSettings: {
        host: "localhost",
        user: "_appName_",
        password: "_password_",
        dbName: "_appDB_"
    },

    ...

};
```

Note the `module.exports`.  If that's missing, or if it's namespaced (like `module.exports.foo`) or if that `dbSettings` object is nested inside something else, it won't work.

Comment: Yes, it is inside module.exports. No, it is not nested inside anything else. Thanks for bringing up this point though.

Answer (score 0):

dbSettings is `undefined`. So that must mean that it's not being found by SailJS. If you are using v.1.0 then you need to define your settings in `connections.js` instead of `adapters.js`. I'm assuming Sails will not be able to find your configuration otherwise.